# ActionPack still dependent upon 'old' version of Sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dependencies, sprockets, actionpack

Wondering if someone can help me better understand dependencies in Rails where they're set and, perhaps, why?

I've noticed that for some reason my installations of Rails (ActionPack) are dependent upon a seemingly old version of the **Sprockets** gem (2.1.3 as opposed to 2.4.5 which is "current").

Is this normal or am I carrying some legacy dependency somewhere that I'm not aware of? If normal anyone know why Rails team might be ignoring the updates to Sprockets? Just curious...

```
$ gem list sprockets

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

sprockets (2.4.5, 2.1.3)

$ gem cleanup
You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    sprockets-2.1.3
actionpack-3.2.8 depends on [sprockets (~> 2.1.3)]
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [Yn]  n
Unable to uninstall sprockets-2.1.3:
    Gem::DependencyRemovalException: Uninstallation aborted due to dependent gem(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say a lot about the reasons behind it, but this commit should have fixed it in the current 3-2-stable branch:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/83e0c952d6823964ead68437c280583ac8a00ce4

This should also answer the question on where those dependencies are set.

Let's hope for a soon Rails 3.2.x release, so we can use the current sprockets.

Comment: Rails 3.2.9 *still* requiring old sprockets: `actionpack-3.2.9 (sprockets (~> 2.2.1))`. I must have something set up wrong because the current sprockets is at v2.8.1 !?!